# Android Studio Logcat keeps collapsing text

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I updated `Android Studio` to version `2022.1.1 Patch 2` and since then it keeps collapsing the text in the `Logcat` and also the `Run` panel. Please tell me there's a way to disable this ?! I've looked all over the usual places but couldn't find anything.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- right-click in the console or Logcat and select ***Fold Lines like this*** option
  [image]
- Then in the next popup window search for the keywords that cause the lines to collapse. For example, in my case, all lines starting with **`GETX`** were collapsed. So I removed it and then all lines starting with **`GETX`** word were visible in the console.
  [image]

Comment: I already tried that, but I hate NO idea which one of these is the one with the problem ...  Any ideas ? Not sure what removing them all will break :) Cause i'd sure like to try to :)) https://pastebin.com/vWCY0NtT